Installing OneDrive per-machine seems to cause the OneDriveUpdate scheduled task to fail
Installing OneDrive per-machine seems to cause the OneDriveUpdate scheduled task to fail.
On one computer i had:
Last Run Result: 0x8004EE05
return code was: 2147806725
Last Run Result computer 1
Return Code Computer 1
On another computer I had
Last Run Result: 0x8004EE39
return code was: 2147806777
Last Run Result computer 2
Return Code Computer 2
A third computer
Last Run Result: 0x800C0005
return code was: 2148270085
All machines with per-user installs appear to be working.
I do not understand why, I cannot even find the result code or the return code listed above on searching google and bing and different forums.
Anyone had similar issues? Any idea on the codes above?

and what is the issue to do it per user based? Or what speaks against it?

Well would like to be able to manage it more easily. Right now I can only find a way to install silently with the per machine install.
If i try to install silently per user it doesnt install.
Would also prefer users to have less control over the program itself and not be able to accidentally uninstall it.

These returncodes are probably wrong, probably caused by a software bug. Wrong returncodes can also be caused by hardware failures, like CPU-, RAM-, HDD-, SSD-, PSU-failures. PS software bugs can also be caused by computer worms/viruses
